# how to insert current date in mysql database using jsp?

Tags: java

I am trying to insert the date using this code:

```
java.sql.Timestamp sqlNow=new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
pstTimestamp(1,sqlNow);
```

On running the code, the result is successful, but the date is not been displayed in the database.

Comment: Provide more code and details

Comment: Where is JSP in coming into picture?

Comment: What is pstTimestamp(1,sqlNow); Is it your customized method? If yes then please provide the code as well.

Comment: basically i am making a registration page ...

Answer (score 5):

You should use `PreparedStatement` and use it to set the `date` as follows :-

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table_name (col_name) VALUES (?)");
pstmt.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()));
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Read more [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table_name (col_name) VALUES (now())");
ps.executeUpdate();
```

use `now()` so that it will get the date in db format only.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you commit after running the command. Or make sure auto commit is enabled on the connection.

Comment: @ Rakhitha :by default auto commit is enabled on getting the connection until you are not setting it to false manually.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to provide the `java.sql.Timestamp` class object to the `PreparedStatement` object rest of work will be done by driver.
I think there is a problem in your code while setting place holder's value(parameter).
Use `pstmnt.setTimestamp(int index, java.sql.Timestamp timestamp_object);`
now execute your query as: pstmnt.executeUpdate();